# How to make an array of hashes in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

How to make a `hash` that has been pushed into an `array` independent of the "source" `hash`?

```perl6
my %country;
my Hash @array;

%country{ 'country' } = 'France';
@array.push(%country);
%country{ 'country' } = 'Germany';
@array.push(%country);

.say for @array;
```

The output is:

```perl6
{country => Germany}
{country => Germany}
```

And of course it's not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push the hash `%country` on to the array you are pushing the reference to `%country`. In this way, each array element will reference the same original hash `%country`. And when you change a value of the hash all array elements will reflect this change (since they all reference the same hash). If you want to create a new hash each time you push it, you can try push an anonymous hash instead. For example:

```
%country{ 'country' } = 'France';
@array.push({%country});
%country{ 'country' } = 'Germany';
@array.push({%country});
```

In this way, a reference to  a copy of `%country` is pushed each time (instead of a reference to `%country`).

**Output**:

```
{country => France}
{country => Germany}
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent a lot of time to localize this problem and now after inserting `{` and `}` the whole program works as expected. :) My question is, why the problem occurs when pushing `hashes` but not when pushing scalar variables? `my $x = 1;
my @values;
@values.push($x);
$x = 2;
.say for @values; # 1`

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I think scalars are pushed by value, but hashes are pushed by reference. That's why the difference :)

Comment: Also according to the [documentation for routine push](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/push): *"push does not attempt to flatten its argument list. If you pass an array or list as the thing to push, it becomes one additional element"*

Comment: So if I want to be sure pushing anything above a scalar, I just have to put inside `{}`, and it will flatten?

Comment: Not if you have an array to push. Then you would use an anonymous array instead. Since square bracket produce an anonymous array, that would be `@array.push( [@myarr] )`. Note however that since you declare `@array` as an array of hashes, you will not be permitted to push arrays to this array.

Comment: And if I have an array of variables of other types (e.g. sets etc.)? What's the general rule of creating an anonymous variable?

Comment: Note that sets are immutable, so I think it would not make mush sense to make a copy in an anonymous variable here. But other types would need other approaches I think. I am not aware of general approach yet. For example consider a `SetHash` variable  `$fruits`, then you could use `clone` to make a copy:   `@array.push($fruits.clone)`

Comment: Of course I meant `SetHash` :) So, for `Array`, `Hash` and `SetHash` we should use three different approaches (`[]`, `{}`, and `.clone`)?

Comment: Yes that is what I can come up with for now:) But I agree this should be unified. Currently it is not possible to `.clone` hashes and arrays. You can call `.clone` on them, but it will not actually clone them as far as I can see. Maybe you could try patch `.clone` on arrays an hashes and after that `.clone` could be used as general approach?

Comment: Not sure that my skills will permit me to do it. :) Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 3):

Just about every programming language has this issue. You're pushing the same hash onto the array more than once. When you change the hash, you change both references that are inside the array.

If you push different hashes onto the array, you'll see the result you expect:

```
my %a = ( country => 'China' );
my %b = ( country => 'USA' );
my Hash @array;
@array.push(%a);
@array.push(%b);
say @array.perl;
```

You can even copy the hash when you push it onto the array, instead of declaring two hashes. That will also solve this problem:

```
my %country;
my @array;
%country<country> = 'México';
@array.push(%country.list.hash);
%country<country> = 'Canada';
@array.push(%country.list.hash);
say @array.perl;
```

By the way, there are a lot of ways to copy a hash. The key is to get the key/values, then turn it back into a hash. Which hash constructor, and which flattening method you use are up to you. (`.kv`, `.list`, `.pairs`, `.flat` are all `Hash` methods that will get the elements sequentially, in one way or another. The way Håkon showed is more implicit, getting elements then creating another hash by syntax alone.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! Why doesn't this happen when pushing a scalar variable? How to know beforehand, with which type of variable this will be a problem?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky most single values are immutable (Int/Str/DateTime) so when you change it what you are actually doing is putting in a new value instead of modifying an existing one.

Comment: @BradGilbert So the problem will occur for all the mutable types of variables? Is there a general solution?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Yeah, the solution is to not share objects that you don't want a different part of the code to modify. It's also good programming practice to not modify objects that are "owned" by another part of the code. Also, when a function returns data from a class, it can return a version of the data which is immutable. For example, instead of returning an array, return an iterator of that array. (You avoid making an extra copy, but still return data which doesn't allow the caller to make any unexpected changes.)

Comment: @EugeneBarsky The problem is you aren't realizing that you are changing them differently. `my $a = 1; ++$a; # ($a = $a + 1)` vs `my $h = Hash.new('a' => 'b'); $h{'a'} = 'c'; # ( $h.STORE_AT_KEY('a','c') )`

Comment: Thanks to everyone! In which part(s) of p6 docs is this explained *in extenso*?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I wouldn't expect to find this in the Perl 6 documentation (though perhaps someone mentioned it somewhere). It's more of CS 101 pitfall. Okay, probably not the first CS class, since it involves mutable data structures within data structures, but this is a general programming pitfall, beyond the scope of Perl 6 tutorials or reference.

Comment: @piojo As you may guess, I don't have sufficient CS background, so I'll be grateful for any further suggestions.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky The basic guidelines I can think of are: a function should never modify its arguments unless the API makes it clear that that's what's happening (like by parameters being name named "foo_out" or keywords specific to the language). And if some logic gets a member of an class instance by calling a getter, it should have extreme caution when modifying that object, in case it's still being used (permanent data, not temporary). In general, I suggest thinking about shared ownership of objects. Each piece of data should logically have one "owner", and no one else should modify it.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky And containers (like arrays) allow variables to be shared that otherwise couldn't be, like integers. In the vast majority of programming languages, having `int i = 0; foo(i);` can't ever change the value of `i` (languages are designed this way partly for performance reasons, partly because it's behavior people expect). But if you want this integer to change, you can put the integer in an array, and send the array to that function. Arrays are shared, and the function can modify `array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple key value pair (not a multi part hash) consider Pairs?

```
my Pair @array;
@array.push( (:country<Germany>) );
@array.push( (country => "France") );
say @array;
say .kv for @array
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! In general I have to use a hash with many kv pairs.